# Log transformation with negative values

Tags: regression, data-transformation

This may for sure be a basic question but suppose a model

\begin{equation}
 y = \alpha  \times r^\gamma \times \varepsilon
\end{equation}

the parameters $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are of interst for me (and $\varepsilon$ is the standard error term). so my first intention was do take the $log()$ of the function. however, i know that the **$y$ may be negative**. any hints for this situation?

Comment: Why do you want to $\log(\cdot)$ this model? If $y$ can be positive or negative, then this model clearly can't be fit on the log-scale.

Comment: @Macro Well I guess if r had to be positive the log transformation would lead to an additive linear model on the log scale. But the domain of the log is x>0.  But oddly if gamma is an even integer you can take the log(r$^γ$)=γlog(-r) when r<0.

Comment: How about using a Gaussian GLM with a log-link, i.e. `glm(y~log(r),family=gaussian(link="log"),...)`, which corresponds to `y ~ Normal(exp(a+b*log(r)))`, which sounds like what you want?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to add a constant to both sides of the function so that y is always positive? (I know, a question should not be answered with a question!)

Comment: Aren't you actually fitting $y=\alpha r^\gamma \mathbf{+} \epsilon$?

Comment: *Why* can $y$ be negative?  If it is only because $\alpha$ may be negative, there is an obvious solution (take logs of the absolute values); if it is because $\varepsilon$ has positive probability of being negative (and positive probability of being positive), then we have an interesting problem!

Comment: @Seb This might not being an answer to the question but I wasn't able to find a way to comment your post. I'm facing exactly the same problem and I wanted to ask how you lately solved it. Thanks for the hints.

Comment: There are solutions. But you need to give more details. Is $r>0$? Also, do you have truncation (e.g. cases where $y$ is *exactly* 0)?

Comment: @user603 r is a matrix of distances in meter and therefore all the elements are positive. Furthermore truncations never occurs.

Comment: Welcome to this site, @Yann. For your information, you cannot post comments before having earned 50 reputation points on this site (hence the automatic migration of your answers to comments that moderators are performing for you).

Comment: @Yann to be honest I left this model and went on with some other formula -- therefore I haven't thought about the problem. I guess the proposal by Michael Lew could be worth a try (at least it worked for me in some other context).

Comment: can't we do when x is positive do normally `log(x)`. if x is negative do `-1*log(abs(x))`.  may be not applicable for above case (because i don't know what OP wants). but useful for scaling issues with data. i don't see anyone talking about this method. please comment.